# Unable to view tabs except the current one in Sugar Pro 6.3.0 after changing tab order

Tags: tabs, show-hide, sugarcrm

I am using Sugar 6.3.0 and have got an error when i have changed the tab order from

> Admin ->  Display Module Tabs and Subpanels

I only see the current tab on my web page and all other tabs are not visible to me and the screen also displays the following errors

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  var/www/workspace/clientname/modules/MySettings/TabController.php on line 71 Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/workspace/clientname/include/GroupedTabs/GroupedTabStructure.php on line 77 Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /var/www/workspace/clientname/include/GroupedTabs/GroupedTabStructure.php on line 93 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/workspace/clientname/include/GroupedTabs/GroupedTabStructure.php on line 110

I can change the tab by changing the ?module=MODULENAME in the url if for example i set ?module=Accounts i can see the Accounts tab but only and only Accounts tab all the other tabs are gone.

Any idea what i am doing wrong and how to resolve it?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you update to the 6.3.3 release and see if the issue is resolved there?

Comment: I have compared the 6.3.0 files with fresh 6.3.3 files but event It dosen't work. Anyway jmertic can you kindly explain what is the meaning of 'group_0' in $tabs->set_system_tabs($_POST['group_0']); this code snippet i have taken from modules/Administration/Savetabs.php When i use print_r($_POST) there is no key with name 'group_0' and thats why 'group_0' is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all we have found the solution for resolving this problem in Sugar Pro 6.3.0 What we have to do is rename or delete the file named SaveTabs.php present in the modules/Administration folder after that make a repair and then reorder the tabs and save it. Hope it will work fine at least for us it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
 I think you have done modifications to module through module builder and redeployed it.This is not the correct way.We need to do modifications through studio only.

 Try to do repair through repair wizard or otherwise use backup.There is any other solution i think.I have tried a lot.
```